# How to transform this recursive function to iterative

Tags: c#, recursion, iteration, combinations

I would like to replace this function by a iterative version.
I found some versions that accept unique inputs.

```
private static void FindCombinations(char[] A, string output, ref int counter, int i, int n, int k)
{
    //Console.WriteLine($"i:{i} n:{n} k:{k} r:{output}");
    if (k == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        counter++;
        return;
    }

    for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
    {
        FindCombinations(A, output + " " + A[j].ToString(), ref counter, j + 1, n, k - 1);
        while (j < n - 1 && A[j] == A[j + 1])
            j++;
    }
}
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string output = "";
    char[] keys = new char[] { 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
    int count = 0;
    FindCombinations(keys, output, ref count, 0, keys.Length, 3);
    Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? Also, if you can explain in words what the method is supposed to do, that would also help.

Comment: This algorithm come from https://www.techiedelight.com/find-distinct-combinations-of-given-length/ and I just activated the option where input has duplicate values

Comment: Great, although it would be better to put your own words on it. Please [edit] your question and put the information there instead of a link (a good question should explain the problem itself). Please also add the attempt you have made.

Answer (score 0):

The next time, you have to provide first your code attempts as this community is not programming for you, it is trying to help you program. Also,  some more context would be much appreciated.

Anyway, I think this method below should work for you. Check if it works for many different cases, specially for boundary conditions. Surely this code can be optimized (I just tried to mimic what your recursive methods does), but as you are just asking for non-recursive code, it should suffice:

```cs
 private static void FindCombinations2(char[] A, string output, ref int counter, int i, int n, int k)
        {
            i = Math.Max(i, 0);
            n = Math.Min(A.Length, n);
           
            char[] A_used = new char[n - i];
            Array.Copy(A, i, A_used, 0, n - i);

            int[] indexVect = new int[k];
            for (int j = 0; j < indexVect.Length; j++)
                indexVect[j] = j;

            int L = A_used.Length;

            string currentBase = output;
            int movingIndex = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                int indexA = indexVect[movingIndex];

                if (indexA >= L)
                {
                    indexVect[movingIndex] = movingIndex;
                    movingIndex--;                    
                    if (movingIndex < 0)
                        break;
                    currentBase = currentBase.Substring(0, currentBase.Length - 2);
                    continue;
                }

                char nextA = A_used[indexA];
                currentBase += " " + nextA;
                int t;
                for ( t= indexVect[movingIndex]+1; t< L; t++)
                {
                    if(A_used[t]!=nextA)
                    {
                        indexVect[movingIndex] = t;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (t >= L)
                    indexVect[movingIndex] = L;


                movingIndex++;
                if (movingIndex >= k)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(currentBase);
                    counter++;
                    movingIndex--;
                    currentBase = currentBase.Substring(0, currentBase.Length - 2);
                }
                else
                    indexVect[movingIndex] = Math.Max(indexVect[movingIndex], indexA+1);
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: My intention was not to hurt anyone! Thank you for your answer